# how to create controller/view for /home

Tags: java, spring-mvc, netbeans

I have a project template which after login page is opening /restricted/home page successfully. I want to open /home page after login. In my authenticatedcontroller I changed it to

```
modelAndView = new ModelAndView("redirect:/home");
```

Now its showing /home url in browser but with `http status 404` page is showing.
I want to create a SystemController.java file that will take care of such urls

```
/
/home
/system
/system/user
```

what setting I need in which file to point my above requests to SystemController?

Its Spring MVC 3.0 based project.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe that is what you need:

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/home", "/system", "/system/user", "/"})
class SystemController {
    return new ModelAndView("view");
}
```